# Using meteg to mark non-ultimate accented syllables

Tags: grammar-dikduk, prayer-book

The common practice in current prayer books is to use a *meteg* to mark the stressed syllable in non-biblical texts if it's not the last one. The earliest edition using this method I have found is R' Heidenheim's siddur ([this particular copy](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH002504911/NLI) is from 1806). In [R' Emden's siddur](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=227) from 1745 there's no such marking yet. On the other hand, in [Isaac Satanow's siddur](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23772&st=&pgnum=45) from 1785 *all* stressed syllables are marked with a *meteg,* even in case of words with ultimate stress. Do we know who came up with the current system? Alternatively, could you find earlier editions than the *Safah Berurah* with the current solution?

Comment: The prayer book edited by the grammarian רבי שבתי סופר מפרעמישלא in the 16th century marks all accented syllables with a meteg.

Comment: @paquda I've been looking for his prayer book for a while on the internet. Is it available somewhere?

Comment: The wikipedia page ha links to several editions online: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8#%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95

Comment: My grandparents' wedding bencher has a meteg even on the last syllable.  I don't know who printed it, but they got married in New York in the late 50s.  It's a little pink hardcover book that contains the kind of things you'd see in more recent benchers, but also birchos hashachar, and it has the Star Spangled Banner and Hatikvah in the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heinrich Guggenheim credits Wolf Heidenheim with this system in the introduction to his Haggadah. He writes:

> Heidenheim also was the first to print the *meteg* when the accent is not on the last syllable.

I can't find another place where this is stated explicitly. However, although he doesn't explicitly claim it as his invention, Heidenheim does devote two full pages to explaining his system and the need for it in the introduction to his siddur שפה ברורה (see pages 9 and 10 [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990025049110205171/NLI)).

On the other hand, Yosef Ofer (in an article in [Leshonenu vol 64](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i24330026), pp. 297–313) credits this to Seligman Baer in his siddur עבודת ישראל (see the bottom of p. 299). I'm not sure what to make of Baer postdating Heidenheim; perhaps Ofer meant that it was popularised by Baer.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>* He also writes (footnote 8) of a 14th-century Italian mishna manuscript that marks the accent with a *meteg* mostly for non-ultimately-accented words, ie. the system in question. It sounds like it's not 100% consistent in this respect, so this may not be a proper example. You can see the beginning [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b10541994j/f32.item.r=hebreu%20328.zoom), where in the first mishna, תכלת has a *meteg* in one occurence but not in another, and דרך has no *meteg* in its first occurence. The third mishna is much more consistent, however.</sup>

Comment: Good old _weiberteutsch!_ Although it's not 100% sure, I find it quite compelling that he had to explain this in the introduction…